# Observable returned by service won't complete

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, angular2-http

I have a service that uses angular's http service

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getThings() {
    return this.http.get('url').map((res) => {
      // massage data here and return massaged data
    });
  }
}
```

I use the service like this

```
this.myService.getThings.subscribe(
  things => {},
  err => {},
  () => {
    // never completes...
  });
```

How come `myService.getThings()` never completes although `http.get('url')` completes ?

How can I make `myService.getThings()` complete ?

Comment: this could be interesting for you: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7865

Comment: did you solved this issue?

Comment: i used the finally method

Comment: consider to choose an answer so your question gets marked as solved

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the `finally` operator in case that you want to execute code when the stream emits its last value (completes).

For example:

```
//Inside of a component
this.fooService.getFoos().
finally(()=>console.log("Completed"))
.subscribe(foos => this.foos = foos);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible that it does not complete because of websockets or other mecanisms as stated in the github issue : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7865 ;
but here are two plunkr with Angular2 and Angular4, both using a mock json file through HTTP, and in both cases the observable completes correctly.

In both cases I've setup a similar case to yours :

```
this.toto().subscribe(
      (result) => {
        console.log('result => ', result);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('error => ', error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('comlete');
      }
    });

  toto() {
    return this.http
    .get('test.json')
    .map((res) => res.json());
  }
```

Plunkr1 : http://plnkr.co/edit/hoIyMHl8abhaG7BYVyns?p=preview

Plunkr2 : http://plnkr.co/edit/siVrOIIvT1uWP36LkiOZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The http.get('url') does not "complete" because all that does is map the response sent from your server.

One thing to note here about Observables: They do not actually do anything until they are subscribed to. Secondly, the following code:

```
return this.http.get('url').map((res) => {
  // massage data here and return massaged data
});
```

returns an Observable, which is just a function that returns a stream of data.

Another thing to note about Observables is that not all Observables will complete inherently. Observables only complete if their source completes. In this case, the http.get() function does complete, so that is not a concern for you.

Lastly, Observables will not complete if they trigger an error. In the case of the http.get() function, an error is triggered if the server produces any response that is not a 200 level response.

I suggest that you change your getThings function to include the `catch` operator:

```
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

return this.http.get('url')
   .map((res) => {
      // massage data here and return massaged data
   })
   .catch((error: Response) => {
      return Observable.throw(error.status);
   });
```

If an error occurs from the get() request, it will return an Observable containing the status from the server. Then you can take a look at the status and see what the issue is.

Comment: Depending on the architecture needed your suggestion for a `catch` clause does not help. Instead of having the complete error object propagated to the `subscribe` you now only get the `status` field in the `onError`.

Answer (score -1):

The "complete" block won't be executed if some error occurred in the process. (Does not work as a Finally).

Put some log in all steps to find if occurred some error.